# How to check if player is on the wall in Unity 2D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I make a simple 2D game, where the player must jump up. I create a map with Tilemaps. For a player to jump, he must touch the ground.
Example:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    if(other.transform.tag == "Ground")
    {
        IsGrounded = true;
    }

}
```

Now a small problem: If the player touches even from the bottom, to the left or right of the collider, then the isGround becomes true and the player can jump from the wall. How can I disable this?

Comment: Make another smaller collider at the feet of the character, and place the isgrounded logic there.

Comment: Normally that things are managed throug raycasts. I'll suggest to download the 2d player controller made from standard assets on the asset store, and learn from that.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to accomplish this. The way I would do it is dig into the Collision2D object. From it you can get an array of ContactPoint2D's using `other.contacts`, which can tell you the direction of the surface you have collided with.

Something like:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    if(other.transform.tag == "Ground" && other.contacts[0].normal == Vector2.up)
    {
        IsGrounded = true;
    }

}
```

The `other.contacts[0].normal == Vector2.up` is checking the "normal" direction of the first contact and comparing it to the world "up" vector.